# Assertions In A Mock Callout Test

Tags: apex, rest-api

Working on my first call out class. When a contact is created or has an email changed we need to make a call out to a third party service that verifies the email address.

Everything is working excep the final assertion. I expect a result of valid but the result is null. I have been reading through the documentation but not making sense of the rules around DML and mocks.  I have included my call out class, test class and Mock. How can I get my assertion to pass and validate that the field I want updated by my callout has been updated?

Web-service

```
public with sharing class NeverBounceCallout {

@Future(callout=true)
public static void checkNeverBounce(Id id){
    Contact  contact = [SELECT Email, Never_Bounce_Result__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: id LIMIT 1];
    String email = contact.Email;
    String url = 'https://api.neverbounce.com/v4/single/check?key={api_key}&email=' + email;

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(url);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

            contact.Never_Bounce_Result__c = (String)results.get('result');
            System.debug('json body = ' + results);
            update contact;
        }
    }
}
```

My Mock

```
@IsTest
global class NeverBounceMock implements HttpCalloutMock{

global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request){
    System.assertEquals('GET', request.getMethod());

    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    response.setBody('{"status" : "success", "result" : "valid"}');
    return response;

}
```

Test

```
@IsTest
private class NeverBounceTest {
@IsTest
static void NeverbounceEmailTest() {
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test acc');
    insert a;
    Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Con', AccountId = a.Id, Email='Test@test.com');
    insert c;

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new NeverBounceMock());
    NeverBounceCallout.checkNeverBounce(c.Id);
    Contact contactToCheck = [SELECT Never_Bounce_Result__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: c.Id LIMIT 1];
    //System.assertEquals('valid', contactToCheck.Never_Bounce_Result__c);
    Test.stopTest();

}
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to set this -- `contact.Never_Bounce_Result__c = (String)results.get('result');` instead? The reason being your mock response returns an attribute named `result` instead of `results`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** here is because of the way you are testing a **`future` callout**.

Because the updates are being carried out in a future method, thus while asserting, you don't get the value while you are asserting it between `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`. Refer to this [trailhead on how to test future methods](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_future_methods), except below (emphasis mine).

> The system collects all asynchronous calls made after the `startTest`. When `stopTest` is executed, all these collected asynchronous processes are then run synchronously. **You can then assert** that the asynchronous call operated properly.

So you will need to make the assertions in your test class, after `Test.stopTest()`.

```
Test.startTest();
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new NeverBounceMock());    
NeverBounceCallout.checkNeverBounce(c.Id); 
Test.stopTest();

// assertion now
Contact contactToCheck = [SELECT Never_Bounce_Result__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: c.Id LIMIT 1];
System.assertEquals('valid', contactToCheck.Never_Bounce_Result__c);
```

You will still need the below details to make sure your response returns correct value.

---

Your mock returns:

```
response.setBody('{"status" : "success", "result" : "valid"}');
```

and that you are trying to set the value of an attribute named `results` (notice the extra s here):

```
contact.Never_Bounce_Result__c = (String)results.get('results');
```

And thus your field `Never_Bounce_Result__c` would have never been set with the expected value here, thus failing your assertion.

For your assertion to work, you will need to set `result` as expected in the response and that it should be written as:

```
contact.Never_Bounce_Result__c = (String)results.get('result'); // no ending s here
```

Or, if you expect `results`, then that attribute needs to be set in the response accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jayant and thank you. I did make that change you suggested. But forgot to edit my post. The assertion still fails. I will update now.

Comment: Have you put a debug to see what do you receive when you query it, no assertion, just a debug.

Comment: The debug in the class with a query shows a value of (Contact:{Never_Bounce_Result__c=valid  I just can't the assertion to pass

Comment: @BrooksJohnson I have updated my answer based on what I found while trying to replicate this issue.

Comment: @JayantDas Was JUST about to write a new answer with that information!

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I completely missed the `future` annotation at the first place and had in fact thought all wrong as how it was behaving here.

Answer (score 5):

Notice how you set the value in this field:

```
contact.Never_Bounce_Result__c = (String)results.get('results');
```

Does your mock ever set a `results` attribute? No. You need to add this attribute to your JSON map (`'{"status" : "success", ...}'`).

Comment: Hi Adrian, I made that change and verified it in the debug log but the assertion is still failing.  I  updated the code above. And thank you for your help.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson Check your singular/plural. It's `result` in the mock's response and  `results` in the class. BTW - you'd have been better off debugging the Contact field in the class, since that's what your assert is testing.

Comment: Yeah you need to use `{..., "results": "value"}`.